# JSON path evaluation

Tags: json, extract, gatling

given this node in a json response:

```
 {
  "name": "RFM912Feilkode",
  "valueCodeableConcept": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://xxx/error-code",
        "code": "0"
      }
    ],
    "text": "OK"
  }
```

I want to verify that the text "OK" is present in Gatling using Scala syntax.

Something (pseudo code ish):

```
  .check(jsonPath("$..valueCodeableConcept.text").is("OK"))
```

but this does not work. Any tips on how to "hit" the OK value and check if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Your json isn't valid. Missing curly bracket.

I tried this and all works fine:

```
.check(jsonPath("$.valueCodeableConcept.text").is("OK"))
```

Comment: The json is huge so I just pasted a bit in. However, if I want to specify each of these nodes by using the system name as selctor how would one do that?
{
      "name": "KJFeilkode",
      "valueCodeableConcept": {
        "coding": [
          { "system": "http://xxx/sfm-kj-rf-error-code",
            "code": "0"
          } ],
        "text": "OK" }
    },
    {
      "name": "RFM96Feilkode",
      "valueCodeableConcept": {
        "coding": [
          { "system": "http://yyy/sfm-kj-rf-error-code",
            "code": "0"
          }],
        "text": "OK" }

Comment: this works, but I want 2 checks, one for each of the urls.
   .check(jsonPath("$..valueCodeableConcept.text").is("OK"))

Comment: so how do I say "check that the text has value OK for system=xxx/sfm-kj-rf-error-code and for system=yyy/sfm-kj-rf-error-code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract some json based on other elements in the json (what you seem to be getting at in the comments on other answers), then you can use filters in the jsonPath like

```
$.[?(@.name=="RFM912Feilkode")].valueCodeableConcept.text
```

which will get you the `text` element from `valueCodeableConcept` where the associated `name` is `RFM912Feilkode`